# force win 11 to open pdf files with older version of acrobat

Tags: acrobat-pro-dc

I have installed Acrobat X Pro on a wind 11 pro pc, and after that I installed Acrobat DC, whenever I open a pdf file its opened by Reader DC and I can not change it. Even if I use "open with" and select Acrobat X (where I use the app on my pc option) it does not stay that way. How can I in regedit force Windows to open pdf files with Acrobat X?

Note I installed Acrobat DC after Acrobat X because I need to be able to use the pdf preview window in file explorer.

Comment: Check in Acrobat Pro, Edit menu, Preferences, General, to scroll down to "Default PDF Handler" and change that to Adobe Pro. Let me know what happens.

Comment: I don't think 1 association will be able to pick from 2 Adobes.   Make the association for Acrobat DC (I do this) and open / use Acrobat X manually. There is no automation I know for this.